# The specification of modern, non-communicating cipher machinery

Tags: encryption, symmetric

I'm looking for references, papers or guidance on a class of system which I have not seen widely discussed.

Consider powerful electronic machinery which remains in the custody of communicating parties, is reasonably insulated from tempest-style attacks, and which is not networked. Between tasks its state is completely reset, and includes no secret material such that the hardware may be considered entirely open.

The machinery is used to convert telegraphically-short plaintext to ciphertext (or back again) by means of a large, symmetric randomly-generated key, and the ciphertext is communicated to the recipient non-electronically and without the aid of electronic communications technology, presumably by laborious means (eg writing, semaphore, Aldis lamp). Similarly, keys are not stored electronically, but by some other painstaking means, so must also be as short as humanly possible (eg memory). Identity is not securely established or managed by the system.

If the act of communication were electronic, a default implementation might be to generate a random IV, encrypt the message with a respected symmetric block-cipher in CBC mode, and append an HMAC generated with a well-respected hash function.

However, for such communication to be successful when transmitted more laboriously, size is of the essence, particularly when also padded with ECCs, and with symbols drawn from a small alphabet. Questions I'd like to be more confident on include: what guidance is there for the length of IVs? What threats would be opened up by failing to include an HMAC? Given the vulnerability to errors, what are good approaches (if any) to resynchronization after corruption? What are the principal vulnerabilities and attack vectors of such a system, to the extent that it has been specified (beyond learning the key)?

Systems such as these must have been considered in the literature, but I can find little written about such a set up? Perhaps I am lacking some vital terminology which is thwarting searches? Is the system so simple that there's nothing to discuss?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70362/discussion-on-question-by-dan-sheppard-the-specification-of-modern-non-communic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "tricks" are

Build "arbitrary-size [FPE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) with [associated data](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/4694)" by using

[S2V](http://eprint.iacr.org/2006/221.pdf#page=10)$\:\:$($\:\:$master_key$\:\:$,$\:\:$associated_data || plaintext_length$\:\:$)

as the key for [format-preserving encryption](http://www.iacr.org/archive/fse2007/45930457/45930457.pdf)s with a disjoint domain for each possible $\:$ plaintext_length .

and

Map pairs $\:\langle$nonce,plaintext$\rangle\:$ into the domain determined

by the plaintext's length via an efficiently invertible [injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

and

If the FPE decryption gives something that is not in the

range of that injection then the ciphertext is not valid.

and

Try to keep the nonces secret.

(Encrypting the same plaintext with the same nonce associated data will obviously produce the same ciphertext. $\:$ Thus, if an adversary knows that the same nonce was used and sees the same associated data but different ciphertexts, then the adversary can deduce that the plaintexts were different.

However, if an adversary doesn't know the nonces, then it can't distinguish between that case and the case in which the same plaintext was encrypted with the same associated data but different nonces.)

.

For any domain $\mathcal{C}_{\hspace{.02 in}n}$ of ciphertexts, with $\mathcal{M}$ the space of plaintexts of the corresponding length

and $\mathcal{N}\hspace{.03 in}$ the corresponding set of nonces, the probability of a single attempted forgery

$\langle$ associated_data , $c\hspace{.04 in}\rangle\;\;$ for $\;\;c\in \mathcal{C}_{\hspace{.02 in}n}\;\;$ being accepted will be $\;\;\; \frac{\left|\hspace{.01 in}\mathcal{N}\hspace{.03 in}\right| \hspace{.03 in} \cdot \hspace{.03 in} |\hspace{.02 in}\mathcal{M}\hspace{.01 in}|}{\left|\hspace{.02 in}\mathcal{C}_{\hspace{.03 in}n}\hspace{.02 in}\right|}+\epsilon \;\;\;\;$.

(Obviously, if there are multiple attempted forgeries, then there will

be a greater probability of at least one of them being accepted.)

Furthermore, even if that probability is large, decryption results will indistinguishable

from  being "as close as possible" to independent samples from the distribution

with probability $\:\frac{\left|\hspace{.01 in}\mathcal{N}\hspace{.03 in}\right| \hspace{.03 in} \cdot \hspace{.03 in} |\hspace{.02 in}\mathcal{M}\hspace{.01 in}|}{\left|\hspace{.02 in}\mathcal{C}_{\hspace{.03 in}n}\hspace{.02 in}\right|}\:$ of being a random plaintext of the corresponding

length and with probability one minus that fraction of being rejections.